# How to determine $f^{-1}$ for $f(p) = (1 + X)p' + p$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ \mathbb{R}_2[X] $ be the vector space of polynomials with real coefficient and a degree less or equal $2$.
>
> $f$ is the map of  $ \mathbb{R}_2[X] $ into $ \mathbb{R}_2[X] $ defined as:
>
> $$ f(p) = (X + 1)p' + p $$
>
> with $ p \in  \mathbb{R}_2[X] $.
>
> 1. Prove $f$ is an endomorphism.
> 2. Prove $f$ is invertible and determine $f^{-1}$.

---

1. $f$ is linear because we have: $f(p + \lambda q) = f(p) + \lambda f(q)$ for $p,q \in  \mathbb{R}_2[X] $.

We have: $deg((X + 1)p') \leq 2$ and $deg(p) \leq 2$

$\implies deg(f(p)) \leq 2$

$\implies f(p) \in  \mathbb{R}_2[X]$

$\implies f( \mathbb{R}_2[X] ) \subset  \mathbb{R}_2[X]  $.

Which proves $f$ is an endomorphism.

2. We have: $\dim Im(f) = \dim  \mathbb{R}_2[X] $

$\implies f$ is bijective, hence invertible.

This is the part I am stuck in. To determine $f^{-1}$, I need to determine the matrix $A$ of $f$ in the basis $\{1, X, X^2 \}$ and find its inverse $A^{-1}$. Which I don't see how.

Are my answers correct? How can I determine the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor answers are correct. You should elaborate a liitle bit more why $Im(f)=\mathbb R_2[X]$.

We have $f(1)=1$, hence the first column of $A$ is $(1,0,0)^T$.

$f(X)=1+2X$, hence the second column of $A$ is $(1,2,0)^T$.

$f(X^2)=2X+3X^2$, hence the third column of $A$ is $(0,2,3)^T$.

Comment: How can I elaborate more on than? Thank you for your answer. =)

Comment: Show that $ker(f)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Can I say that according to rank-nulity theorem we have: $\dim Imf + Kerf = \dim \mathbb{R}_2[X]  \implies \dim kerf = 0 \implies kerf = {0}$ ?

Comment: First show that $ker(f)=\{0\}$. Then you get , by the  rank-nulity theorem: $\dim im(f)=\dim \mathbb{R}_2[X] .$

Comment: $f(p) = 0 \iff (X+1)p' + p = 0 \iff (1 + X)(2aX + bX) + (aX^2 + bX + c) = 0 \iff aX^2 + (2a + b)X + 2b + c = 0 $, since $\{ 1, X, X^2 \}$ are linearly independent, we have $a=0, 2a + b = 0,2b + c = 0  \implies a = b = c = 0 \implies p = 0 \implies kerf = {0}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Accepted answer. =)